# trying to click on a POPUP on a web page using vba

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Need to click on a popup which is an image on a webpage so i can gather data from that page. I have tried this line. i inspected the element in ie and i believe it is ("N58:Attachment:0").

I tried the following
IE.Document.getElementsByName("N58:Attachment:0").click but nothing happens

the html is the following

```html
<td class="x1w x57">
<span id="N58:Attachment:0">
<a onmouseover='showFiles(this,"Attachment::Attach_1_::ATTACH_/xxoa/oracle/apps/xxoa/webui/RFQDetailsPG.Attachment::FRED.MILLER_BSSWUSA.COM::3840999::false::false::false::false::ATTACHMENT_IMAGE","xxoa.oracle.apps.xxoa.serv.RFQAM","_","ItemsTable","132989","RF.jsp?function_id=ATTACHREST&amp;security_group_id=0&amp;isReadOnlyCustomPopup=Y")' onmouseout="clearAttTimer()" onclick="submitForm('DefaultFormName',0,{'_FORMEVENT':'EntityName=MULTI&amp;PO_LINE_ID=3840999&amp;AttachRegKey=ATTACH_/xxoa/oracle/apps/xxoa/webui/RFQDetailsPG.AttachmentcWwNUmMH','attachStyleParam':'ATTACHMENT_IMAGEEjyLVGNL','PO_LINE_ID':'3840999YvHMu5kE','serverValidate':'09gDNpf_y',event:'oaGotoAttachments'});return false;" 
onfocus='showFiles(this,"Attachment::Attach_1_::ATTACH_/xxoa/oracle/apps/xxoa/webui/RFQDetailsPG.Attachment::FRED.MILLER_BSSWUSA.COM::3840999::false::false::false::false::ATTACHMENT_IMAGE","xxoa.oracle.apps.xxoa.serv.RFQAM","_","ItemsTable","132989","RF.jsp?function_id=ATTACHREST&amp;security_group_id=0&amp;isReadOnlyCustomPopup=Y")' 
onblur="clearAttTimer()" 
href="#">
<img align="middle" alt="View" src="/OA_MEDIA/attachments_toggleattach_popup.gif" border="0">
</a>
</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Try `IE.Document.getElementById("N58:Attachment:0").getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click`

Comment: for the image _ie.document.querySelector("img[alt=View]").click_    ; for the a tag try _ie.document.querySelector("[onmouseover*=showFiles]").click_

Comment: IE.Document.getElementById("N58:Attachment:0").getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click (worked thanks a bunch)